# Google Chrome extension - Webdb or IndexDB

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-sql

we are in process of developing google chrome extension, in which we need to store all the video information from a particular website. so we are considering the option of webdb.
and now we are getting confused between to use webdb or indexdb..

As of now i think that, indexdb is still experimental, is that correct? 
and, if we use indexdb, the db even will not show up in dev. tools db section, where as webdb will show up, so that we can do query stuff in there..

please shed some light and put us in correct direction

Comment: The W3C document deprecating WebSQL notes that two storage-related specifications are still under development: Web Storage (sessionStorage and localStorage) and Indexed Database API (indexedDB). Since chrome.storage (an extension of localStorage) is stable and documented in http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html, the more pertinent question would be "localStorage or indexDB?" One reason to prefer chrome.storage is the ability to sync across devices. One reason to prefer indexDB would be to store more data than the default 5MB quota for localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IndexedDB. WebSQL has been [officially deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) and will be removed from Chrome in the future. The dev channel of Chrome has [experimental](https://plus.google.com/118110542957297456336/posts/BvryKXAkrEv) dev tools support for viewing IndexedDB databases.

Comment: Wow.. worked like charm.. now i can see IndexedDB in dev. tools. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dave comments re the question should be included below the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few months since I checked, but based on the work I did then, I would suggest WebSQL. The primary reason is that support is complete (it's basically SQLite). Here's what I wrote at the time:

> If you're doing web app development and need to utilize a local
>   (client-side) database, you should be using either localStorage
>   (assuming you can live with the limitations of size and limited
>   queries/indexing) or WebSQL. IndexedDB is not a contender yet, as
>   essential functionality such as deleteDatabase is missing from for
>   instance Chrome. WebSQL doesn't give you schemaless functionality
>   without any glue, but on the other hand it works great (has a lot of
>   uses outside of browsers as well), has full features functionality and
>   probably limited or no practical size limitations.

In addition, the debug console (at that time) had WebSQL support, and no IndexedDB support. Things may have changed and YMMV, but at least you should be aware.